# Using PostGIS Intersection to carry fields from input layers into output layer

Tags: postgis, intersection, fields-attributes

I'm having trouble carrying over the attributes from the input layers in my PostGIS intersection below:

```
CREATE TABLE intersection_output AS 
(SELECT ST_Intersection(a.the_geom, b.the_geom) FROM nyct2010 as a, test_buffer as b WHERE ST_Intersects(a.the_geom, b.the_geom))
```

I specifically want to carry over the field **geoid** from nyct2010 and **observation** from test_buffer.

I've tried this, but doesn't seem to work:

```
ST_Intersection(a.the_geom a.geoid, b.the_geom.observation)
```

Comment: Perhaps `SELECT ST_Intersection(a.the_geom, b.the_geom), a.geoid, b.observation FROM` but it is a bit hard to understand which fields you want to pick. Knowing the schema of the tables would help, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109325/postgresql-describe-table and do `\d+ tablename`

Comment: You should create an answer for your solution rather than editing the question ([answering your own questions is perfectly acceptable](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)).

Comment: Thanks Evil Genius, wasn't sure I should do to that. Will answer in sep. post from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @user30184, this worked:

```
CREATE TABLE test_intersect_output AS (SELECT  ST_Intersection(a.the_geom, b.the_geom), a.geoid, b.observation FROM nyct2010 as a, test_buffer as b WHERE ST_Intersects(a.the_geom, b.the_geom))
```

The key piece that worked is this:

```
(SELECT  ST_Intersection(a.the_geom, b.the_geom), a.geoid, b.observation
```